# React onChange is not updating on input change

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I am trying to update my state with an onChange on my input. Currently, onChange on triggers when I press enter. How would I go about updating my state without having to press enter?

```
  onChange(e, key) {
    const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
    if (e.target.value === "" || re.test(e.target.value)) {
      this.setState({ [key]: Number(e.target.value) });
    }
  }

  inputFigureRow(title, amount, key) {
    return (
      <div style={styles.benchMarkRow}>
        <div style={styles.titleRow}>{title}</div>
        <input
          key={key}
          style={styles.inputValueLeft}
          value={amount}
          onChange={e => this.onChange(e, key)}
        />
        <div style={styles.valueRight}>${amount}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderContent() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.root}>
          <div style={styles.benchMarkContainer}>
            {this.titleRow()}
            {this.inputFigureRow(
              "Sales Target",
              this.state.salesBenchMarkTarget,
              "salesBenchMarkTarget"
            )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  render({}, state) {
    return this.renderContent(state);
  }
```

Comment: `inputFigureRow` is component or just a function?

Comment: its just a function.

Comment: How this function is called? If possible update complete running code.

Comment: I updated with the render.

Comment: why you use `\b` in your regex?

Comment: @ravibagul91 I am not familiar with regex. It's copy pasta that worked for me tbh.

Comment: what you want to test, what you want in your input?

Comment: @ravibagul91 When the value of the input is changed I want it to automatically update state. Say if the input had the numebr 5 in it and then I add a 0 to it I want the state to automatically update to 50 without the need to press enter.

Comment: `onchange` is firing correctly, try to put console.log("as first line"), as  a first line in `onChange`

Comment: @ravibagul91 It logs once and no more when I change what in the input.

Comment: Just try to remove `\b` from your regex.

Comment: can you put this code in https://codesandbox.io/s/l4w3o6my59 so that I can have a look.

Comment: @Ryan113 It's weird, since you are not binding your `onChange` function.
Try to use it in this way `e => { this.onChange(e, key) }` note the curly braces, not returning the function.

Comment: And also as @ravibagul91said, remove the `\b` in your regex

Comment: removed \b from regex

Comment: @RubenSaucedo Isn't that the way I have it?

Comment: @Ryan113 have you tried my solution? The problem is onChange fires when you enter / blur from a changed input. OnKeyDown fires every key press...

Comment: @andymccullough Yes, I did and gave the checkmark. Thank you.

Comment: @andymccullough This is actually not correct. [onChange](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#onchange) fires on every change in React

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onKeyDown` handler on your input instead of `onChange`. If you need to wait for the last character, you'll need to introduce a debounce interval, e.g https://blog.flowandform.agency/debounce-in-react-fc5ed305a0e8